# Unable to restore scroll position on auto refresh

Tags: html, css, angular5

In my angular 5 project,all the contents on HTML page are formed from an object that is defined in Typescript Component.That object is auto-refreshed after 4 seconds.Therefore the scroll bar drags to top automatically after those 4 seconds.How do I fix the position of the scroll bar even if data is refreshed after few seconds?

Comment: You need to remember scroll position, and then restore it after refreshing. BTW, it shouldn't scroll to top itself. May be you are reducing the height below browser height and then adding the content. Resulting in this behaviour.

Comment: Actually I have created multiple horizontal tabs which are collapsed by default, so I have to expand the tab to view its content and have to store the expanded tab id.But due to auto refresh it takes me to top of the page.